# Syntactical issue using generics

Tags: java, generics

This is a homework problem:

I have a generic class defined as follows:

```
public class PriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    ArrayList<T> queue; 

public PriorityQueue(){
    queue = new ArrayList<>();
}

void add(T t){
    queue.add(t);
    Collections.sort(queue);
}

<T extends Comparable<T>> T remove(){
    T t = queue.get(0);
    queue.remove(t);
    return t;
}
}
```

but NetBeans is showing the following error (red-underline) on the line `T t = queue.get(0)`:

```
incompatible types
required: T#2
found:    T#1
where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
T#1 extends Comparable<T#1> declared in class PriorityQueue
T#2 extends Comparable<T#2> declared in method <T#2>remove()
```

It seems as though somehow it's not understanding that the `T` type I'm referring to in the method declaration is the same as the one referred to in the type parameter of the class. I'm guessing this is some sort of a syntax issue.

I also wonder if I'm overcomplicating things - it would seem more logical to me if I simply declared the method with `T remove() {`. This compiles correctly, but when I try to test it using a driver class as follows:

```
    PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

    int a = 10;
    int b = 12;
    int c = 5; 
    int d = 9;

    pq.add(a);
    pq.add(b);
    pq.add(c);
    pq.add(d);

    Integer i = pq.remove();
```

I get the error:

```
Incompatible types: 
required: Integer 
found:    Comparable
```

on the line `Integer i = pq.remove();`

As is probably obvious, I'm just learning how to use generics. Please help me understand where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: p.s. for best results use `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

to

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
```

remove method should be

```
T remove() {
...
```